# How do I access the view of a Window from interfacebuilder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to make interfaces for a cocoa app in xcode's interface builder. The view of one of the windows I made in Interface builder depends on data from another view, so it is necessary to message this view from the class which must pass it data. However I can't seem to find a way to get a reference for this view object from the owner of the nib file. Here is roughly the code I'm using:

```
controller = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Somenibname"];
[[controller window] display];
theOtherView = [[[[controller window] contentView] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
[theOtherView setObjectwhichneedstobemessaged:self];
[theOtherView sendAMessage:self];
```

The object that this code is in never receives the message. Initially I actually thought that the contentview was the view that appears in interface builder and tried to get a reference to it like this

theOtherView = [[[controller window] contentView]];

but that didn't work either. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need a better understanding of how the View-Controller structures work with nib files and without more code/detail its difficult to know exactly what you are trying to do, but a quick way to solve your problem could be to use NSNotification's instead of trying to locate the other view and instigate a message send via call chain.

You can register to handle a notification from the receiving view and send the notification from the instigating view (and vice versa if you need it two ways).

Answer (score 1):

Read up on `IBOutlet` and consider linking the views that you need directly from Interface Builder.

For example, your `NSWindowController` subclass might have:

```
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController
{
  /* can also use more specific classes if you need them, e.g. NSButton if it's really an NSButton */
  IBOutlet NSView* firstViewIWant;
  IBOutlet NSView* secondViewIWant;
}
  . . .
@end
```

Your implementation might have:

```
- (void)
windowDidLoad
{
  [super windowDidLoad];
  /* make sure the views were connected properly */
  assert(nil != firstViewIWant);
  assert(nil != secondViewIWant);
    . . .
}
```

Then in Interface Builder, hook up these outlets from "File's Owner" to the exact views that you need them to be.